# OpenCV highgui110.dll Link Error

Tags: dll, opencv

i encounter an error like

```
Error 1 fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2C8 C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin\highgui110.dll
```

Additional Include Directories

```
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cxcore\include
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs\highgui
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\cv\include
```

Additional Library Directories

```
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\otherlibs
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\lib
C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin
```

Additional Dependencies

```
cv.lib
highgui.lib
cxcore.lib
highgui110.dll
```

Error Message is

```
Error 1 fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2C8 C:\Program Files\OpenCV\bin\highgui110.dll 1 OpenCV Capture
```

What wrong with highgui.dll ?

Please help.

Thanks.

This is my source code.

Code:

```
#ifndef CAM_CAPTURE_H
#define CAM_CAPTURE_H


#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

class CamCapture
{
private:
CvCapture* myCaptureHandler;
IplImage* videoFrame;
int key;

public:
CamCapture();
~CamCapture();

void Init();

};


#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove highgui110.dll from your list of Additional dependencies. In additional dependencies you should list only lib files.